# Serial Dispatch Queue with Asynchronous Blocks

Tags: multithreading, cocoa, swift, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

Is there ever any reason to add blocks to a **serial dispatch queue** *asynchronously* as opposed to *synchronously*?

As I understand it a serial dispatch queue only starts executing the next task in the queue once the preceding task has completed executing. If this is the case, I can't see what you would you gain by submitting some blocks *asynchronously* -  the act of submission may not block the thread (since it returns straight-away), but the task won't be executed until the last task finishes, so it seems to me that you don't really gain anything.

This question has been prompted by the following code - taken from a book chapter on design patterns. To prevent the underlying `data` array from being modified simultaneously by two separate threads, all modification tasks are added to a serial dispatch queue. But note that `returnToPool` adds tasks to this queue *asynchronously*, whereas `getFromPool` adds its tasks *synchronously*.

```
class Pool<T> {
    private var data = [T]();
    // Create a serial dispath queue
    private let arrayQ = dispatch_queue_create("arrayQ", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    private let semaphore:dispatch_semaphore_t;

    init(items:[T]) {
        data.reserveCapacity(data.count);
        for item in items {
            data.append(item);
        }
        semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(items.count);
    }

    func getFromPool() -> T? {
        var result:T?;
        if (dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER) == 0) {
            dispatch_sync(arrayQ, {() in
                result = self.data.removeAtIndex(0);
            })
        }
        return result;
    }

    func returnToPool(item:T) {
        dispatch_async(arrayQ, {() in
            self.data.append(item);
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(self.semaphore);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are reasons why you'd add tasks to serial queue asynchronously. It's actually extremely common.

The most common example would be when you're doing something in the background and want to update the UI. You'll often dispatch that UI update asynchronously back to the main queue (which is a serial queue). That way the background thread doesn't have to wait for the main thread to perform its UI update, but rather it can carry on processing in the background.

Another common example is as you've demonstrated, when using a GCD queue to synchronize interaction with some object. If you're dealing with immutable objects, you can dispatch these updates asynchronously to this synchronization queue (i.e. why have the current thread wait, but rather instead let it carry on). You'll do reads synchronously (because you're obviously going to wait until you get the synchronized value back), but writes can be done asynchronously.

(You actually see this latter example frequently implemented with the "reader-writer" pattern and a custom concurrent queue, where reads are performed synchronously on concurrent queue with `dispatch_sync`, but writes are performed asynchronously with barrier with `dispatch_barrier_async`. But the idea is equally applicable to serial queues, too.)

The choice of synchronous v asynchronous dispatch has nothing to do with whether the destination queue is serial or concurrent. It's simply a question of whether you have to block the current queue until that other one finishes its task or not.

Regarding your code sample code, that is correct. The `getFromPool` should dispatch synchronously (because you have to wait for the synchronization queue to actually return the value), but `returnToPool` can safely dispatch asynchronously. Obviously, I'm wary of seeing code waiting for semaphores if that might be called from the main thread (so make sure you don't call `getFromPool` from the main thread!), but with that one caveat, this code should achieve the desired purpose, offering reasonably efficient synchronization of this pool object, but with a `getFromPool` that will block if the pool is empty until something is added to the pool.

Comment: Your explanation of why ``getFromPool`` makes most sense as a synchronous call, in contrast to ``removeFromPool``, was very useful.

Answer (score 3):

Because there's no need to make the caller of `returnToPool()` block. It could perhaps continue on doing other useful work.

The thread which called `returnToPool()` is presumably not *just* working with this pool. It presumably has other stuff it could be doing. That stuff could be done simultaneously with the work in the asynchronously-submitted task.

Typical modern computers have multiple CPU cores, so a design like this improves the chances that CPU cores are utilized efficiently and useful work is completed sooner. The question isn't whether tasks submitted to the serial queue operate simultaneously — they can't because of the nature of serial queues — it's whether *other* work can be done simultaneously.